# Two way binding in Expression Blend 4

Tags: .net, silverlight, data-binding, expression-blend

How does Blend 4 decide (in Silverlight 4) whether a Binding created in designer is OneWay or TwoWay? 
I've bound an integer from an INPC class to a DependencyProperty on my custom control, but it only generated a *{Binding Something}* instead of a *{Bindig Something, Mode=TwoWay}*.
So I've put a *[Bindable(true,BindingDirection.TwoWay)]*, but that did nothing, and the remarks for BindingDirection.TwoWay made no sense too, since it says things about "templates exposing properties"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Silverlight (unlike WPF), the [Binding.Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode%28VS.95%29.aspx) property defines:

> One of the BindingMode values. The default is BindingMode.OneWay.

If you don't specify this, you'll get a OneWay binding.

Comment: WPF also has FrameworkPropertyMetadata.BindsTwoWayByDefault whereas SL does not...

Comment: @Aaron: Yes.  It's tricky to force SL to bind two ways.  There's no documented guidance (at least that I've found) showing how to do it.

Comment: You seem to misunderstood my problem. I'm writing a CONTROL, which has a bindable dependencyproperty, which others will use in Blend. If they use the Blend's Binding designer, it generates a {Binding} string, but WITHOUT Mode=TwoWay.

Comment: But I've seen it done on built-in SL controls. (Like ListBox's SelectedItem) Are they all coded into Blend???

Comment: @TDaver: You have to hand edit those bindings, I believe, and not rely on blend's default binding declaration.

Comment: also, whats up with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.bindablesupport(VS.95).aspx ?? "Yes" = "not for binding", "No"="not for binding" ??

Comment: @TDaver That defines if the property is bindable. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aex19bb8.aspx Don't get confused between a bindable property and a DependencyProperty...

Comment: @Reed Copsey: I'm accepting because your comment, since the answer had nothing to do with my question...

Comment: @Aaron: That's EXACTLY what I need, no I'm not confusing anything. I'm pretty sure of myself, I was asking whether Blend looks for my attribute at all. Reed Copsey says it doesn't. I then asked, why is both values for Bindable has the remark "Not for binding".